# Unexpected RegNotifyChangeKeyValue() Behaviour

Tags: windows, winapi

[`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724892%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
function can provide alerts to changes in the security of a registry key.
I, possibly mistakenly, expected it to alert the caller if the permissions
of the user calling `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` were changed to deny the
user read permission.
From testing it does not inform the caller of this change, nor does it
inform the user of any subsequent changes to the key nor does it fail
in anyway: **the caller is completely unaware that it is no longer being
informed of any change**.

Code (stackc.c):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    HKEY h_key;
    HANDLE h_event;

    DWORD last_error = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                                      "Software\\stackoverflow-testing-key",
                                      0,
                                      0,
                                      REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                                      KEY_READ,
                                      0,
                                      &h_key,
                                      0);

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != last_error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create key: %d\n", last_error);
        exit(1);
    }
    RegCloseKey(h_key);

    last_error = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                              "Software\\stackoverflow-testing-key",
                              0,
                              KEY_NOTIFY,
                              &h_key);

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != last_error)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open key: %d\n", last_error);
        exit(1);
    }


    h_event = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    if (h_event)
    {
        int change_count = 0;
        while (change_count < 2)
        {
            DWORD wait_status;

            last_error = RegNotifyChangeKeyValue(
                             h_key,
                             FALSE,
                             REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_NAME         |
                               REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
                               REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_SET   |
                               REG_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
                             h_event,
                             TRUE);
            
            if (ERROR_SUCCESS != last_error)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to notify: %d\n", last_error);
                break;
            }

            wait_status = WaitForSingleObject(h_event, INFINITE);

            if (WAIT_FAILED == wait_status)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Wait failed: %d\n", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
            if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == wait_status)
            {
                printf("Registry key changed!\n");
                change_count++;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(h_event);
    }
    RegCloseKey(h_key);

    RegDeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\stackoverflow-testing-key");

    return 0;
}
```

Build commands:

> cl.exe -nologo -c -DWIN32 -Zi -MT -W4 -Ox stackc.c -Fo./stackc.obj
>
> link.exe -NOLOGO -INCREMENTAL:NO -OUT:stackc.exe stackc.obj Kernel32.lib advapi32.lib

I am running Windows XP Service Pack3 x86.

To test I executed `stackc.exe` and ran the Registry editor
(`Start->Run "regedit.exe"`), browsed to
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\stackoverflow-testing-key`
and right-clicked and selected `Permissions`, selected the user
which I was executing `stackc.exe` as and denied read permission.
I then added a value to the key and `stackc.exe` is never notified.

Can someone provide an explanation for this behaviour or, preferably,
point to an error in the posted code?

Comment: Lemme guess, you got only one notification?  Kinda hard to generate the LAST_SET notification when you deny read permission.

Comment: @HansPassant, I get zero notifications.

Comment: Okay, I'll pull the other tooth, what happens if you *don't* change the permission.

Comment: @HansPassant, I am not following you here. Something is obvious to you but isn't to me. If I make non-permission related changes to the key notifications are received. If I change the permission to deny read, no notification is received and no notifications are received for subsequent non-permission related changes (which I can understand as the user no longer allowed read access). If I change the permission to allow read a notification is received and subsequent non-permission changes result in notifications being received.

Comment: In the simple permission editor dialog "Read" includes "Notify", so you are denying yourself the permission required to receive notifications.  I would have thought that it would still work since you already have an open handle to the registry key with notify access, though.  Anyway, as long as you are allowed notify access you will get the notifications.

Comment: @Luke, never noticed that "Read" includes "Notify" but I would still have expected to be notified (or at least for the currently running call of `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` to return with failure) of the change and for the subsequent call to `RegNotifyChangeKeyValue()` to fail.

Comment: That sounds like an edge case to me, it might not be possible.  Try enabling backup privilege and using REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE in the call to RegCreateKeyEx, this might (or might not!) prevent you from being locked out of the key.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, thanks. Unfortunately this was just to illustrate the problem and I will not be responsible for the creation of the key. The best I could come up with was to not wait `INFINITE` and re-open the key, thus detecting the change in permissions. Not ideal but could find no other way.

Comment: @hmjd: you can use RegCreateKeyEx to open an existing key.  Just replace the RegOpenKeyEx with RegCreateKeyEx, so that you can use REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE.  You'll need to enable backup privilege first.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, cheers. Will give that a try.